# Ubuntu networking issue

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

we have `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` running on Hyper-V.
Connectivity to Ubuntu is unstable. Pings are stopping every 5-10 seconds for few timeouts from management station in different vlan. But if i ping from server to station or to outside server it stopps less frequently.

`cat /var/log/syslog` do not show any suspicious lines. 
It seems like a problem with OS itself, because other servers on same or different vlan are working correctly.

This OS is freshly installed.

`top` shows cpu 0% utilization, free memory 3.7GB

How to troubleshoot further?

EDIT: i also tried installing legacy network adapter in `Hyper-V` but then checking in  `etc/network/interfaces` is old `eth0` but `ifconfig -a` shows interfaces `enp0s10f0` and `lo`

Comment: How do you assign ip address on Ubuntu? Do you use Network Manager?

Comment: It was assigned after install through `interfaces`

Comment: Is `managed` parameter `false` in config file `/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`? Interfaces names in `interfaces` file must be the same as in output of command `ifconfig`.

Comment: in `/etc` there is no `NetworkManager`

Comment: OK. Then try to regenerate MAC address of this VM after it was powered off.

Comment: I tried static `Mac` address then again added `dynamic` , still same loss

Comment: I also disabled IPv6 in `sysctl.conf`
`net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1`


and in /etc/default/grub
added
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1" `

Comment: MAC can't be static or dynamic. It isn't​ ip address.

Comment: On Hyper-V it can

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic symptoms of an IP address or MAC address conflict. Was the VM copied from somewhere?

Comment: No it was not copied. It is fresh install. Also when ping succeds from management station `arp -a` do not show entry for that ip adress. How could it be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed after changing IP address. Still don't know if it was duplicated on network.